# Property 'allSettled' does not exist on type 'PromiseConstructor' ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Using ts-loader in webpack I get error:

```
 TS2550: Property 'allSettled' does not exist on type 'PromiseConstructor'.
```

typescript version `4.3.4`

tsconfig:
target `esnext`
lib `["es2015", "es2020.Promise", "dom"]`

the error only shows up when compiling in webpack

Comment: That's definitely part of `es2020.promise`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7cbcfeea9989f33689ee69fdcbdefb9e1521bbb3/lib/lib.es2020.promise.d.ts#L34-L49

Comment: I know, but I still get the error, like ts-loader doesn't read the tsconfig lib array

Comment: So that suggests that your config is not actually being applied by TS-loader, but without a [mre] it's hard to say why.

Comment: you are right!
before I do this, any ideas how find out if ts-loader does use my tsconfig?